# Kia Cerato 2009 won’t start - dash lights won’t work

Tags: engine, electrical, ignition

Yesterday I disconnected the battery and reconnected it again (correctly) so I could change a head light as it was very hard to reach. 
Once the battery was reconnected my car wouldn’t start and my dash would not light up. The car is still turning over but won’t start. 
I have tested every fuse and relay in my car and they are all in perfect working order. All wires surrounding the battery (area we touched) are in perfect condition also. 
I understand in newer model cars that if you reconnect a battery you need to clear an error from the Ecu. However when I have plugged in the OBD I am not receiving any message and it is stating to make sure the ignition is on and the DLC is connected. Which both were. I’m considering the poasiblility that this may be an issue with the ECU and that I will most likely have to replace it. But before I go spend $1200 I would like any suggestions on what might have happened!? Thank you!

Comment: Confirm B+ on terminal 16 of the DLC. Recheck your fuses with a multimeter. It's unlikely that the ECU was damaged. If you think everything else is fine, get a second opinion from a professional before you decide to replace the ECM.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!